# Is a subsequence of a sequence of positive functions increasing, if the sequence of the integrals is increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: Let $D$ be a domain of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ $(N\geq2)$, and $(f_{n})_{n}$ a sequence of locally integrable functions on $D$. Suppose that the $f_{n}$'s are positive and the sequence of the integrals:
$$\left(\int_{B}f_{n}(x)d\mu \right)_{n}, $$
is increasing ($\mu$ is the $N-$dimensional Lebesgue measure and $B$ a ball relatively compact in $D$). Here is my question: Is there a subsequence $n_{k} $ such that $(f_{n_{k}})_{k}$ is increasing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your title asks about a subsequence of functions, but the end of your question asks about their integrals.  Which do you want to be increasing?  (I suspect you did not want an integral near the end of your question.)

Comment: Sorry! Yes. I want $(f_{n_{k}})_{k}$ to be increasing...(I corrected)

Comment: Do you assume that this holds for every such ball $B$, or for one fixed ball?

Comment: @PhoemueX Your version of the question makes more sense, and is more interesting than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $f_n(x)=n^2 {\bf 1}_{(0,1/n)}(x)+{1\over n}{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x).$
Then $\int_{(0,1)} f_n(x)\,dx=n+1/n$ which is increasing, but for $n>1/x$
 the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Glad to be of help!